# Returning only time using SpinnerDateModel

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I'm currently using a SpinnerDateModel with a JSpinner to set the time in my java swing app. Below is my code:

```
shiftTime = new JSpinner(new SpinnerDateModel());
    JSpinner.DateEditor de_shiftTime = new JSpinner.DateEditor(shiftTime,
            "HH:mm:ss");
    shiftTime.setEditor(de_shiftTime);
    //shiftTime.setValue(new Date()); // will only show the current time
    shiftTime.setSize(108, 22);
    shiftTime.setLocation(436, 478);
    add(shiftTime);
```

however, when I use the .getValue() method to add this selected time into my database (I'm using mySql), the time is being added with the date. I don't want the date, just the time, e.g. 13:59:16.
However, what I'm getting now is "Thu Jan 01 13:59:16 SGT 1970".

Is there a way to override the new SpinnerDateModel() or something to remove the date in my result? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you! :-)

Comment: Assuming that the database field is TimeStamp, why not create a java.sql.TimeStamp from the value return from the JSpinner?

Comment: I'm currently using varchar to store the time in my database! But thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to convert it into desired output:

```
Date date=(Date)shiftTime.getValue();
SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(format.format(date));
```

[`JSpinner.getValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html#getValue%28%29) returns `Object` and you are just printing value returned by default `Date#toString()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) -- and you should be as the java date libraries are horribly broken, your code will look like:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime((Date)shiftTime.getValue());
ISODateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormatter.timeNoMillis();
String dateAsString = fmt.print(date);
System.err.println(dateAsString);
```

If you need further assistance, do leave a comment.